# Focal operations / aggregations on stars_proxy object in R

Tags: raster, r, sf, extract, stars

I have many NetCDF-files that I read in as `stars_proxy`-object. I also have a geopackage that is a multipolygon. I Would not like to extract the mean value for each polygon for each stars_proxy-object.

I don't event know if a stars_proxy object is the best way to do so. But the stars-package provides such great functionality with `st_apply` to aggregate over time or spatially, that I just used the `stars`-package to read the data. There is the `st_extract`-function, however this is only for points.
I'm searching for something like the `raster::extract` or `exact_extract`-functions that also aggregate cells-values intersecting with polygons.

Maybe a "normal" raster is better. I'm just not really sure and would be happy for any pointer:)

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://github.com/r-spatial/stars#raster-and-vector-time-series-analysis-example

Comment: What you're looking for is `aggregate(stars_object, sf_object, mean)`. You can see an example in the tutorial that @gavg712 suggested, and here is another example:
http://132.72.155.230:3838/r/combining-rasters-and-vector-layers.html#extracting-to-polygons-single-band

Comment: Thanks a lot to you two:)! Really appreciate it!